# COD Elite: Does the heat map show where those have died, or where those have gotten kills from?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2, call-of-duty-elite

Here's a screenshot of the heat map for a match on Call of Duty Elite:

[image: cod heat map]

Now, I can't figure out if the heat markers represent where someone was killed, as opposed to where the kill shots originated.  Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They show the places where others have died.

I tested this out with a friend. I played a match, got a kill on him and left the game. I checked the map and it showed the place he died at with heat.